# How to change the linked batch file that embedded in a Word 2013 .docx file?

Tags: embedded

In Word 2013, we would insert an embedded object that link to a batch .bat file as below snapshot.

A sample of such file can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2015/sample%20batch%20bat%20file%20in%20Word%20docx%20file.zip) - double clicking on the embedded file will say Hello in an external command-line console.

[image]

My question is after inserted, I want to change the object so that it links to another .bat file but I wouldn't find where to do that in Word 2013 ribbon.

Please share as you may know how. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You have provided no legend for the indexed images. What do these images represent? In the second image, does using the browse button in the lower #5 let you change the file?

Comment: The images illustrate for the text right above it.

Comment: And what about my last question about using the browse button?

Comment: The browse button is for loading the icon set - nothing related to the linked file. I'll update with a sample .docx file

Comment: @CharlieRB Sample is done. Hope it helps.

Comment: At this point, it seems like it would just be easier to delete the object link and create a new one.

Comment: Unfortunately, as my question posed here, moving to another location will break the embeded .bat file

Comment: @CharlieRB Thanks for the re-create advice. I nee to see what the object linked to.

Comment: If you don't choose `Link to file` it will actually embed a copy of the file into the document. Then there would be no concern about the file location.

Comment: @CharlieRB So sorry Charlie - the batch file need other resources surrouding its in the parent folder. So we need `like to file` solution.

Comment: Thank for trying to give me a workaround idea. I'm asking for modifying/viewing what file is linked to by the embedded

Comment: All of those details are important to include in the question so these long comment threads can be avoided. :-)